# How to calculate the X Y coordinates of an ellipse with only the X and Y radius length?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, elliptic-integrals

I have an ellipse where the radius of x-axis = 100 and y-axis = 30.
I have 3 objects where I want to evenly distribute it along the ellipse.

I have already done this for a circle where both axis' are the same, ex: radius x-axis=100 and y-axis = 100.
I did:

- evenSpace = 360/3.

Object1 (x,y) = (100 * cos(120*180*1) , 100 * sin(120*180*1).

Object2 same thing but instead of '1', it's 2.

Object3 same thing but instead of '1', it's 3.

This worked out fine for a circle, but with an ellipse I can't get it to work because the x-axis radius is much longer than the y-axis. Any help people? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to use an elliptic integral (of the second kind) for this.

Comment: @J.M. Can you give more detail, how this will work?

Comment: @draks: the arclength of an ellipse requires an elliptic integral of the second kind for representation. I distinctly recall posting something in another question how to obtain the elliptic integral, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: It depends on what the OP means by "evenly distributed". The responders are using "equal arc length", but another possibility could be "equal area of sectors from the center". These are the same for a circle, but different for an ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

Under the usual parametrization of ellipse $x=a\cos t$, $b=\sin t$, the arclength function comes out in terms of the [elliptic integral of second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) as 
$$
\int_0^t \sqrt{a^2\sin^2 s+b^2\cos^2 s}\,ds = b\int_0^t \sqrt{1-(1-a^2/b^2)\sin^2 s}\,ds 
$$ 
which in Sage is `b*elliptic_e(t,1-(a/b)^2)`.   I divided this ellipse in three  arcs of equal length:

[image: three points]

using  Sage commands

```
a=100
b=30
t0=find_root(elliptic_e(t,1-(a/b)^2) == (1/3)*elliptic_e(2*pi,1-(a/b)^2), 0, 2*pi)
parametric_plot((100*cos(t),30*sin(t)),(t,0,2*pi)) + point([(100*cos(t0),30*sin(t0))],color='black',size=30) + point([(100*cos(-t0),30*sin(-t0))],color='black', size=30) + point([(100,0)],color='black', size=30)
```